# Open AngleSharp document in Chrome

Tags: c#, html, anglesharp

I am using [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) in C# to simulate a web browser. For debugging purposes, sometimes I want to see the page I am traversing. I am asking if there is an easy way to show the current document in a web browser (preferably the system's default browser) and if possible with current cookie states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very late to the party, but hopefully someone will find my answer useful: The short answer is no, the long answer is, yes - with some work that is possible in a limited way.

How to make it possible? By injecting some code into AngleSharp that opens a (local) webserver. The content from this webserver could then be inspected in any webbrowser (e.g., the system's default browser).

The injected local webserver would serve the current document at its root (e.g., http://localhost:9000/), along with all auxiliary information in HTTP headers (e.g., cookie states). The problem with this approach is that we either transport the document's original source or a serialization of the DOM as seen by AngleSharp. Therefore, there could be some deviations and it may not be what you want. Alternatively, the server could emit JS code that replicates what AngleSharp currently sees (however, then standard debugging seems more viable).

Any approach, however, requires some (tedious?) work and therefore needs to be justified. Since you want to "see" the page I guess a CSS renderer would be more interesting (also it could be embedded in any application or made available in form of a VS extension).

Hope this helps!